# Microsoft Office Excel 2007 can't use Hyperlinks on existing documents after move to DAV offsite location

Tags: ms-office, excel-2007, webdav

I have a Excel work sheet with a lot of hyperlinks (both to external documents and to other tabs on the same document). We recently moved over to a DAV server to have our files easily available from whatever location we are on. The problem is that some of our machines are unable to use the hyperlinks in the existing documents (nor can I create new hyperlinks that work in existing documents).

We have tested this with Windows Vista and Windows 7, both running Office Professional 2007 and neither can get the hyperlinks to work. We have tried on a Windows 7 machine with Office 2010, and this works fine, as well as a recently set up computer with Vista and Office 2007. It only appears to happen on our existing machines.

What we have tried so far;

- Disabled Firewalls
- Disabled Antivirus
- Reconnected using different DAV users

The Windows7 With Office 2010 runs the same Antivirus and Firewall as the other two machines, but they have not been disabled on this machine and it still functions as intended.

Any recommendations on what might be causing this are more then welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem causing this was that the WebDrive program we use to prevent having to authenticate repeatedly used the Username of the machine as part of the virtual server address, this caused issues as our users have both first and last name accounts generating a space in the server name (which is not valid).